# Some months ago I dual booted Ubuntu 22.04 with Windows 10 on my desktop computer. All was working fine until I installed Gnome Shell Extensions

Tags: boot, 22.04

Then I decided that I did not need the Shell extensions, I searched online and probably got ancient info on how to uninstall them. The next day when I tried to boot up Ubuntu 22.04 I got what looks like a Terminal page that reads:

```
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS  doug-24-b019 tty1. doug-24-b019 login:
```

So entered my login. Then:

```
Password:
```

I entered my password. Then:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04..2 LTS (GNU/LINUX 5.19.0-35-generic x86_64) plus 
* Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com
* Management: https://landscape.canonical.com
* Support: https://ubuntu.com/advantage

*Introducing Expanded Security Maintenance for applications. Receive updates to over 25,000 software packages with your Ubuntu Pro subscription. Free for personal use.

Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled.

0 updates can be applied immediately.

9 additional security updates can be applied with ESM apps.
Learn More about enabling ESM apps service at https://ubuntu.com/esm
```

BUT the GUI Ubuntu 22.04 screen will not come up. Windows boots up just fine from the Ubuntu boot loader but not Ubuntu. I think I am basically a Linux newbie having tried Ubuntu years ago with a long number of years in between before trying this present dual boot. Can Ubuntu be repaired?

Comment: Sounds like you may have uninstalled the entire desktop, not just the extensions. Have you tried reinstalling the desktop? `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` 

Comment: Do I need the desktop Ubuntu 22.04 iso file on, say a flash drive to reinstall it matigo?

Comment: Does the bootable iso file on my flash drive have a repair ubuntu ability matigo?

Comment: Matigo, your directions worked. I am now fully operational with Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10 dual boot again. Thank you very much.